# How does this definition for a hash work?

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax

I found code with hash assignment such as follows:

```
@defeat = {r: :s, p: :r, s: :p}
# => {:r=>:s, :p=>:r, :s=>:p}
```

Why are the keys for this hash generated as symbols? Is this a short form of doing this?

```
defeat[:r] = :s
defeat[:p] = :r
defeat[:s] = :p
```

Is there a name for this style of Hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html) can be easily created by using its implicit form:

```
grades = { "Jane Doe" => 10, "Jim Doe" => 6 }
```

Hashes allow an alternate syntax form when your keys are always symbols. Instead of

```
options = { :font_size => 10, :font_family => "Arial" }
```

You could write it as:

```
options = { font_size: 10, font_family: "Arial" }
```

---

Now in your example `@defeat = {r: :s, p: :r, s: :p}`, all ***keys are symbol***. That's why your example `Hash` is a valid construct, which has been introduced since **1.9**.

Comment: Thanks, of course I found the solution right after asking it too: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Hashes.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the hash style {key: value} you're actually declaring a symbol for the key. Like Arup's example,  {:key => value} is the same thing with the implicit form.  So anytime you use : instead of => in a hash, you are creating a symbol as the key.

In your example,  you're creating symbols for both your key and your value.

```
{key: :value } # both are symbols
```